# Unable to create a new PublicationTarget Class with SDL9.5 libraries

Tags: event-system, sites-9.5, add-on

We are working to migrate our SDL8.5 code of EventHandler to SDL9.5. We updated our libraries and the .Net framework to v4.8 and adapted our code to deploy it using the Add ons of Type

> CMEventHandler

AddOns is deployed correctly but when we try to publish an item it gives us an error when trying to initialise a class

> var pubTarget = new PublicationTarget(new TcmUri(_tcmPreview), item.Session);

The error we get is,

> Unexpected item type: TargetType.   Component:
> Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService Errorcode: 805 User: NT
> AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE  StackTrace Information Details:    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.IdentifiableObject.AssertValidId(Boolean
> allowUriNull)    at
> Tridion.ContentManager.SystemWideObject..ctor(TcmUri id, Session
> session)    at
> Com.**.**.EventHandler.PublishItem(RepositoryLocalObject item,
> PublishEventArgs args)

Has anyone else faced similar issue during the migration of SDL8.5 to SDL9.5

Comment: What is the value of `_tcmPreview` and where do you get it from?  Looking at the error it seems it is the TCM URI of a Target Type instead of a Publication Target.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to our problem was to change the

> var pubTarget = new PublicationTarget(new TcmUri(_tcmPreview), item.Session);

To

> var pubTarget = new TargetType(new TcmUri(_tcmPreview), item.Session)

Seems that in the version 9.5 PublicationTarget is not needed anymore

Comment: Thanks for asking and sharing. Indeed, Publication Targets have been removed from the API and configuration as part of changes for Topology Manager. By Tridion Sites 9.5, they're mentioned in the _deprecated_ features, though I thought they were completely gone. :-)

Comment: Well, Publication Targets still exist as a deprecated feature.  If you have existing Publication Targets in your system, everything (including your original code) should still work.